# SQL "GROUP BY" multiple rows ignoring one

Tags: sql, group-by

I am trying to SUM multiple discount values (in customers export csv) if today's date between FROMDATE and EXPIRYDATE.

If I sum the discount values, everything is fine, but if I ask to check if today is between FROMDATE and EXPIRYDATE, it forces me to add the "FROMDATE and EXPIRYDATE" to GROUP BY and it leads to duplicated lines and the SUM doesnt work.

Here is the code, I signed the problematic parts with **

I will appreciate your help a lot!

```
SELECT
CUSTOMERS.CUSTNAME AS 'ERP Code',
CUSTOMERS.CUSTDES AS 'Name',
CUSTOMERS.PHONE AS 'Phone',
(SELECT TOP 1 PHONEBOOK.CELLPHONE FROM PHONEBOOK WHERE 
CUSTOMERS.CUST=PHONEBOOK.CUST) AS 'Mobile',
(SELECT TOP 1 PHONEBOOK.NAME FROM PHONEBOOK WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUST=PHONEBOOK.CUST) AS 'Prop1 Contact Name',
CUSTOMERS.FAX AS 'Fax',
CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS AS 'Address',
CUSTOMERS.STATE AS 'City',
CUSTOMERS.ZIP AS 'ZIP Code',
CUSTOMERS.VATNUM + CUSTOMERS.WTAXNUM  AS 'Goverment ID',
CUSTOMERSA.EMAIL AS 'Email',
**(SELECT SUM (DISCOUNTS.T$PERCENT) WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN zoom#system.dbo.tabula_dateconvert(DISCOUNTS.FROMDATE) AND zoom#system.dbo.tabula_dateconvert(DISCOUNTS.EXPIRYDATE)) AS 'Discount',**
ISNULL(CUSTPLIST.PLIST, -1) AS 'Price Level Code',
(SELECT (PAY.PAYDES) FROM PAY WHERE CUSTOMERS.PAY=PAY.PAY) AS 'Prop2'

FROM CUSTOMERS
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERSA
ON CUSTOMERS.CUST=CUSTOMERSA.CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTDISCOUNT
ON CUSTOMERS.CUST=CUSTDISCOUNT.CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN DISCOUNTS
ON CUSTDISCOUNT.DISCOUNT=DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTPLIST
ON CUSTOMERS.CUST=CUSTPLIST.CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN  CUSTSTATS
ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTSTAT=CUSTSTATS.CUSTSTAT

WHERE  CUSTOMERS.CUST > 0
and CUSTOMERS.CUSTSTAT between -4 and -2

GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.CUSTNAME,CUSTOMERS.CUSTDES,CUSTOMERS.PHONE,CUSTOMERS.CUST,CUSTOMERS.FAX,CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS,CUSTOMERS.STATE,CUSTOMERS.ZIP,CUSTOMERS.VATNUM,CUSTOMERS.WTAXNUM,CUSTOMERSA.EMAIL,CUSTPLIST.PLIST,CUSTOMERS.PAY,**FROMDATE,EXPIRYDATE**

ORDER BY Name;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, may I know why you are adding all the columns in group by clause

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe a CTE will help here, try this:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT CUSTOMERS.CUSTNAME AS 'ERP Code',
           CUSTOMERS.CUSTDES AS 'Name',
           CUSTOMERS.PHONE AS 'Phone',
           (SELECT TOP 1 PHONEBOOK.CELLPHONE FROM PHONEBOOK WHERE 
           CUSTOMERS.CUST=PHONEBOOK.CUST) AS 'Mobile',
           (SELECT TOP 1 PHONEBOOK.NAME FROM PHONEBOOK WHERE 
           CUSTOMERS.CUST=PHONEBOOK.CUST) AS 'Prop1 Contact Name',
           CUSTOMERS.FAX AS 'Fax',
           CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS AS 'Address',
           CUSTOMERS.STATE AS 'City',
           CUSTOMERS.ZIP AS 'ZIP Code',
           CUSTOMERS.VATNUM + CUSTOMERS.WTAXNUM  AS 'Goverment ID',
           CUSTOMERSA.EMAIL AS 'Email',
           **(SELECT SUM (DISCOUNTS.T$PERCENT) WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN 
           zoom#system.dbo.tabula_dateconvert(DISCOUNTS.FROMDATE) AND 
           zoom#system.dbo.tabula_dateconvert(DISCOUNTS.EXPIRYDATE)) AS 'Discount',**
           ISNULL(CUSTPLIST.PLIST, -1) AS 'Price Level Code',
           (SELECT (PAY.PAYDES) FROM PAY WHERE CUSTOMERS.PAY=PAY.PAY) AS 'Prop2'

           FROM CUSTOMERS
           LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERSA
           ON CUSTOMERS.CUST=CUSTOMERSA.CUST
           LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTDISCOUNT
           ON CUSTOMERS.CUST=CUSTDISCOUNT.CUST
           LEFT OUTER JOIN DISCOUNTS
           ON CUSTDISCOUNT.DISCOUNT=DISCOUNTS.DISCOUNT
           LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTPLIST
           ON CUSTOMERS.CUST=CUSTPLIST.CUST
           LEFT OUTER JOIN  CUSTSTATS
           ON CUSTOMERS.CUSTSTAT=CUSTSTATS.CUSTSTAT

         GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.CUSTNAME, CUSTOMERS.CUSTDES, CUSTOMERS.PHONE, 
                  CUSTOMERS.CUST, CUSTOMERS.FAX, CUSTOMERS.ADDRESS, CUSTOMERS.STATE, 
                  CUSTOMERS.ZIP, CUSTOMERS.VATNUM, CUSTOMERS.WTAXNUM, 
                  CUSTOMERSA.EMAIL, CUSTPLIST.PLIST, CUSTOMERS.PAY
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE CUSTOMERS.CUST > 0
and CUSTOMERS.CUSTSTAT between -4 and -2
```

Comment: Hi bro,
It was very helpful, I am SQL beginner, all that I needed is the "WITH Name AS (...", I understood the principle and solved the problem with it.
Now it works well!
Thanks a lot!!!